# Render out random object from array from fetch

Tags: reactjs

I have 250 objects in the array i get from the axios get request, if i want to render out only 100 of the 250 objects but i want it to always be random can i do something like this
array.[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)]?

Here is my code.

```
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [searchCountry, setSearchCountry] = useState('')
  const getData = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all`)

    setData(data)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [])

  return (
    data && (
      <div className="App">
        <SomeContext.Provider
          value={
            <h2>
              <input
                className="search-country"
                placeholder="Search Country..."
                onChange={(event) => {
                  setSearchCountry(event.target.value)
                }}
              />
              <ul id="countries-ul">
                {data
                  .filter((country) => {
                    if (searchCountry === '') {
                      return country
                    } else if (
                      country.name.common
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .includes(searchCountry.toLowerCase())
                    )
                      return country
                  })
                  .map((country) => (
                    <li className="li-card" key={country.name.common}>
                      <Link to={`/country/${country.name.common}`}>
                        {country.name.common}
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                  ))}
              </ul>
            </h2>
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate your logic `Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)` (which will pick a single item randomly in the array) 100 times. Be sure to remove a item in a array when it is picked if you don't wait it to be duplicated.

```
const getData = async () => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all`)
  const LENGTH = 100;
  const picked = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length); // pick a item randomly
    const removed = data.splice(index, 1); // remove it for preveting duplication
    picked.push(removed[0]);
  }
  setData(picked);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much and also very good explained.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you, but you don't have to add a comment saying "Thank you" in Stack Overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Happy hacking :)